# How to set gaps (gutters) in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create some kind of universal component of flex container. This component consists of container and its children in a row.

If there are too many children in a line, those who don't have enough space go to second line. It can be easily achieved with flexbox, but also I want to be able to set gutter between elements. And first and last elements of a line shouldn't have left and right margin respectively.

I do this using negative margin technique, but the problem here is that right margin can provoke overflow issues if container is too big. I can solve this problem adding `overflow: hidden` to cut off negative margin, but it provokes problem with overflowing items inside container (drop-downs, etc).

So now I'm looking for silver bullet, implementation which can satisfy this requirements:

- There are multiple items in a row. Width of items can differ.
- If some items have not enough space, they go to next line.
- There is a gap between items (margin), and first and last item doesn't have left and right margin, respectively.
- Inside container can be placed overflowing content (drop-downs), so I can't use `overflow: hidden`
- Css grid and flexbox can be used

Here is my solution of this problem:
https://jsbin.com/gabumax

And here code from example:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: -10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">Width of items can vary</div>
    <div class="item">This example works</div>
    <div class="item">But there is a problem</div>
    <div class="item">Dye to overlow:hidden</div>
    <div class="item">It is impossible to place here</div>
    <div class="item">Overflowing content</div>
    <div class="item">Such as dropdowns</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works, but the only negative point here is `overlow: hidden`. Because of this I can't place here dropdowns and other overflowing content.

Any better solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 42):

Use `gap` / `row-gap` / `column-gap`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

See more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#gap-row-gap-column-gap)

Comment: This is the solution as of ‘now’, with support in all major browsers. For specification and compatibility see: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the scrollbar to show, you may set your negative margin on the left and top only.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width:31.7em;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;;
  background:yellow; 
}

.wrapper {
   display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left:-10px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;  
  padding: 10px;  
  background-color: red;  
  margin:10px  0  0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">Width of items can vary</div>
    <div class="item">This example works</div>
    <div class="item">But there is a problem</div>
    <div class="item">Dye to overlow:hidden</div>
    <div class="item">It is impossible to place here</div>
    <div class="item">Overflowing content</div>
    <div class="item">Such as dropdowns</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

or negative right margin if document dir is rtl

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  direction:rtl;
}

.container {
  width:31.7em;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;;
  background:yellow; 
}

.wrapper {
   display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right:-10px;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;  
  padding: 10px;  
  background-color: red;  
  margin:10px 10px  0  0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">Width of items can vary</div>
    <div class="item">This example works</div>
    <div class="item">But there is a problem</div>
    <div class="item">Dye to overlow:hidden</div>
    <div class="item">It is impossible to place here</div>
    <div class="item">Overflowing content</div>
    <div class="item">Such as dropdowns</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is such a brilliant simple solution. You have saved me a whole world of pain :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox isn't your best option here. As you describe, gutter solutions are clumsy and inefficient.

A clean and efficient solution is possible with CSS Grid.

Grid wins over flexbox in this area **for now** because Grid accepts the `gap` properties. These properties are not yet available in flex but, as browsers continue to implement the [CSS Box Alignment Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/), the `gap` properties will be available across multiple box models (including flex).

> [**§ Gaps Between Boxes**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#gaps)
>
> While `margin` and `padding` can be used to specify visual spacing
>   around individual boxes, it’s sometimes more convenient to globally
>   specify spacing between adjacent boxes within a given layout context,
>   particularly when the spacing is different between boxes as opposed to
>   between the first/last box and the container’s edge.
>
> The `gap` property, and its `row-gap` and `column-gap` sub-properties,
>   provide this functionality for multi-column, flex, and grid layout.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">Width of items can vary</div>
    <div class="item">This example works</div>
    <div class="item">But there is a problem</div>
    <div class="item">Dye to overlow:hidden</div>
    <div class="item">It is impossible to place here</div>
    <div class="item">Overflowing content</div>
    <div class="item">Such as dropdowns</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jg0w6y8u/)

Comment: Thanks for answer! But css-grid has serious disadvangage: using this technique I can't have items of different width. My aim is to have multiple items of different width (each item has it's own width depending of it's contents). Can I achieve this with css grid?

Comment: Try switching `1fr` to `min-content` in the `minmax()` function. You have multiple options. Just depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Firefox now supports `gap` in Flex layouts:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox-gap