# Resize property on grid items results in overlap of other grid items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a CSS grid that is set to `auto-fill` the columns, to display as many items on a row as will fit.

This is done with: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10em, 1fr));`

I would like to be able to resize selected grid items, which I am trying with:

```
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
```

This works at a basic level, but the content will overlap/stretch over adjacent grid items when resized horizontally:

[image: Unwanted overlapping behaviour]

When resized vertically, the rows below are instead pushed down, so there is no overlap:
[image: Wanted resize behaviour]

**This is the behaviour I want horizontally too.**

I understand this is likely to do with using `auto-fill` for the columns, as when tracks are explicitly defined the stretching works the same on both axes.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 10em);
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10em, 1fr)); */
}

.grid>div {
  background-color: #eeeeff;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="resize">Resize Me</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4crm7bw8/5/)**

Comment: You need only in grid only? or is it ok If I use flex?

Comment: @Manjuboyz If it works, flex is fine. Ideally the horizontally pushed content will flow to the next rows if possible, rather than increasing the width of the page.

Comment: It works like that because the height is a variable, which means we need a variable width to do the same thing horizontally, this will prevent `auto-fill` from doing what it's doing, In grid you're creating columns/rows which you put your elements, not simply aligning elements. As of now there's no way of targeting those columns/rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) to achieve this:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid>div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
}

.grid>div {
  background-color: #eeeeff;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="resize">Resize Me</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Alfie as I said in the answer you can do some css to alter positions and size but the actual is working as you seek. Let me know.

Comment: I just verified its responsiveness too, it works! let me know if it satisfies your business!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is nice but not quite what I need. Too much of the grid behaviour is lost which breaks my design (specifically, the minmax() of the column sizes and its scaling when the page is resized).

Comment: Hmmmm... the issue what I saw was with `grid-template-columns:` this is making the cells not to move!.

Comment: @Alfie check the answer now, I was able to make it clean by giving width to those cells and again move would be same in using `grid` too so you can't expect more that as far as I recall.

Comment: Thanks - I have accepted your answer for now as it does technically do what I asked. However, it would be great to see a grid only answer as there are nuances to grid that are much better for my particular needs.

Comment: Hi @Manjuboyz, Is it possible to achive the same result with css Grid (While Resizing should not affect another div block)

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it defined, the resize works on the items, but not on the column tracks. That's why you're seeing the overlap when resizing horizontally. The columns are fixed in place, based on the `grid-template-columns` rule <sup>1</sup>.

The only way to make the column tracks resize with the items would be if the columns were set to `auto` (content-based sizing), but this cannot co-exist with `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`<sup>2</sup>.

You don't have this resizing problem in the vertical direction because you haven't defined any rows. Therefore,  the grid defaults to `grid-auto-rows: auto` (again, content-based sizing), and the items and row tracks resize in harmony.

But since you want horizontal wrapping, you can't use this technique for the columns. It's clearly a limitation in grid layout.

Try flexbox instead, which isn't a great alternative in this case (especially because it still doesn't support the `gap` property<sup>3</sup>), but it may get you a step closer to your goal.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid > div {
  width: 10em;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="resize">Resize Me</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rh36259e/)

References:

1. [Aligning grid items across the entire row/column (like flex items can)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50234112/3597276)
2. [Why doesn't min-content work with auto-fill or auto-fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52504049/3597276)
3. [How to set gaps (gutters) in a flex container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56977608/3597276), [Setting distance between flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755146/3597276)

Comment: This is the answer I feared, but it is a good explanation of why. Thank you.